# Updating html elements from backend in node.js

Tags: node.js, html, socket.io

So, Maybe I shouldn't do it in the first place but when a player hits the button I want the buttons to disappear and I have to do that with my client side javascript. How could I do that from backend? So for instance I want my app.js to do this

```
  client.on('createGame',function(){
  document.getElementById("startbutton1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("startbutton2").style.display = "none";
  console.log("client host game");

});
```

I am using socket.io and on the create game event I want to delete both buttons the player sees and I don't want the player to client-side change it just to keep from causing problems. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to call an API on button click. The API will respond in true or false and on that basis you hide or show the button.

By this you can avoid the front-end java-script logic.